# Static INotifyPropertyChanged generator for POCO's

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

found this runtime INotifyPropertyChanged generator

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141732/Automatic-Implementation-of-INotifyPropertyChanged

wondering if there is a static generator to avoid the run time performance hit  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Notify Property Waever](https://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver)

> Injects INotifyPropertyChanged code into properties at compile time.

Comment: + Yes that works by injecting the notifications at compile time. I use the Visual Studio extension for Notify Property Weaver. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3

Comment: @RoyGoode: I've been scanning the page and somehow failed to notice the very first sentence which makes it quite clear.

Comment: I would vote up your answer but I've reached the daily limit.

Comment: @RoyGoode: Wow, that would never happen to me :)

Answer (score 0):

[PostSharp's INotifyPropertyChanged aspect](https://doc.postsharp.net/model/notifypropertychanged/inotifypropertychanged-conceptual) injects the boilerplate at compile time using MSIL rewriting.

[Metalama](https://doc.metalama.net/examples/notifypropertychanged) is a Roslyn extension that also allows to generate the INotifyPropertyChanged boilerplate. It does it by AST modification and you can debug the transformed code.